# tensorflow cost function is a tensor, not a scalar - why? Optimization fails

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

the following code runs, but it does not work. The variable `cost` is always a tensor full of 1.0, but why? I estimated a scalar, because a 1x5 matrix multiplied by a 5x1 matrix is a scalar. The biases and weights also do not change while optimization. What am I doing wrong?

```
#KI-Model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 5], name='input') #x_1-x_5


#Init the graph
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

#activation with sigmoid
y = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W) + b) #berechneter Wert für y

#Training
y_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='output')
#cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_tensor * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1])) #Hier Cross-Entropie statt minimum squares method

loss = y-y_tensor
cost = tf.square(loss)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)


#Start
session = tf.Session() #Google-> was ist das?
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session.run(init)


#init first 1000 training_batches
for i in range(1000):
    batch_xs.append([dataA[i], dataB[i], dataC[i], dataD[i],
              dataE[i]])
    batch_ys.append(dataG[i])

for i in range(10000):

    session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_tensor: batch_ys})

    print(session.run(cost, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_tensor: batch_ys}))
```

Comment: A very confusing fact is, that I get the identical values for the cost tensor, when I replace `session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_tensor: batch_ys})
` by
`session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x:[[0,1,2,3,4]], y_tensor:[[2]]})`. So what is wrong with the optimization?

Comment: Your code is working for me with `feed_dict={x:[[0,1,2,3,4]], y_tensor:[[2]]}`, and it's giving me a decreasing cost.  Did you change the print statement so it's also using the fake data?  If you have more code than this, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

loss is a tensor, and tf.square apply the square function to each element of your tensor:

```
loss = y-y_tensor
cost = tf.square(loss)
```

Try to use [a given loss function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses) or a custom one to compute the desired loss.